# Missing All SharePoint Components in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-developer, apps-development, development-enviroment, office-365-develop-tool

- I had installed VS 2015 Community and in my Windows 10 PC,And after
  installation ,
- When I open VS 2015 it is showing as "**BLEND VISUAL STUDIO 2015**"
  And even after installing tools from (https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/office-tools/)      I see SharePoint Components missing in my VS 2015 to develop apps

Can any one help me ,How can I get back SharePoint components

Comment: Pretty sure you can not use SharePoint templates in Community edition

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51683) that will solve your issue as shown below:

[image]

For more details check

- [Missing SharePoint 2016 Project Template in Visual Studio 2015](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/24/missing-sharepoint-2016-project-template-in-visual-studio-2015/)
- [Missing Office / SharePoint template in Visual Studio 2015](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/14/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/)

Comment: I had installed both Preview 1 and Preview 2 ,But I still dont find any luck